# Asp.net Bar Chart with Datatable Columns as X Axis

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, charts

I'm very new at chart objects in ASP.net. I have a single row column that I queried from a SQL database.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| CPass | CFail | WPass | WFail | SPass | SFail | HPass | HFail | APass | AFail |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     3 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     3 |     0 |     5 |     2 |     0 |     0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to attatch it to a chart object on an ASP.net webpage set to a bar chart. How would I set the series so that the column header is the X and the single row of values is the Y?

I feel like this should be easy, but so far Google has let me down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google chart (column chart)

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Here is the fiddle of the sample code

https://jsfiddle.net/L80x1e0t/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Score');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');


      data.addRows([
      ['CPass ', 3],
      ['CFail ', 3],
      ['WPass ', 0],
      ['WFail ', 0],
      ['HPass ', 5],
      ['HFail ', 2],
      ['APass ', 0],
      ['AFail ', 0]

      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Scoring system',
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Score',

        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Frequency'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```